# How to place titles beside each other with pictures underneath html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a part of my website where there are multiple pictures in a row with titles above them. I have made the pictures in a row but am having trouble placing the titles in a row above as well. I have tried using display: inline; for both but it doesn't seem to work. What is the solution to this question.

```css
.mobile_title {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 65px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.web_title {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 200px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

.mobile {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.mobile1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.laptop {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.coding {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.database {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile_title">Mobile Development</div>

<div class="web_title">Web Development</div>

<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x100" width=50 height=100 class="mobile">

<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x100" width=50 height=100 class="mobile1">

<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x100" width=150 height=100 class="laptop">

<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x100" width=150 height=100 class="coding">

<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x110" width=150 height=110 class="database">
```

Mobile title is the first one. I know need to know how to incorporate the other titles in the same line. Thanks so much for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bootstrap's row and column classes is a lot easier to implement than using vanilla css. You can link your html file to bootstrap using their CDN, and add column classes to each title and image set:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
    <div class="mobile_title">Mobile Development</div>
    <img src="mobile.png" width=50 height=100 class="mobile">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
    <div class="mobile_title">Mobile Development</div>
    <img src="mobile.png" width=50 height=100 class="mobile">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what your html code will eventually look like. Make sure all your column classes are wrapped in a row class. 
To add bootstrap to your html code, just follow this link and copy the first link tag you see on the page and paste it at the bottom of your html head section: [Bootstrap CDN](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn)

Answer (score 0):

Use either CSS ***float*** property or use a table. Although using a table as a layout element is not a correct way. It does help out.

Sometimes, CSS float can become really frustrating to work with if you float a lot of elements towards a single side. Using Tables is recommended. Use a row for the Titles and the second row for the images.

```
<table>
<tr><td> Heading 1 </td><td>Heading 2</td></tr>
<tr><td> Image tag 1 </td><td>Image tag2</td></tr>
</table>
```

You can learn more about tables [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know how I would incorporate it. I tried those as options previously but they were the same as display: inline;

Comment: Can you edit the question to include what you've tried?

Comment: Ok. I will try that

Comment: Alright. Do you know how to add that to the code as I have no experience working with rows and tables

Comment: Added sample code and linked to documentation @Kg123

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there a way to make tables responsive for mobile devices

Comment: If it solved your problem please upvote or mark as answer and create a new question, that will  help others who have the same issue get resolution quickly.